# Calculating Buy and Hold return around event date per ID in R

Tags: r, date, if-statement, return

I wrote a similar question yesterday, but then the problem became more complicated as I proceeded, so I would like to ask again.

I have a question about calculating returns in the following case.
For each ID, if Date=EventDate, I hope to calculate "buy and hold return" from 5 days prior to the event date to 5 days after.

To be more specific with the table below, I want to calculate returns around the event date (-5 ~ +5 days) for each ID, where the returns are, for example, (9/10-1), (12/10-1), (14/10-1), ~ , (14/10-1), (17/10-1), (16/10-1) for ID = 1 (That is, the price six days prior to the event date is the denominator in the return calculation.)

```
+----+------------+-------+------------+
| ID |    Date    | Price | EventDate  |
+----+------------+-------+------------+
|  1 | 2011-03-06 |    10 | NA         |
|  1 | 2011-03-07 |     9 | NA         |
|  1 | 2011-03-08 |    12 | NA         |
|  1 | 2011-03-09 |    14 | NA         |
|  1 | 2011-03-10 |    15 | NA         |
|  1 | 2011-03-11 |    17 | NA         |
|  1 | 2011-03-12 |    12 | 2011-03-12 |
|  1 | 2011-03-13 |    14 | NA         |
|  1 | 2011-03-14 |    17 | NA         |
|  1 | 2011-03-15 |    14 | NA         |
|  1 | 2011-03-16 |    17 | NA         |
|  1 | 2011-03-17 |    16 | NA         |
|  1 | 2011-03-18 |    15 | NA         |
|  1 | 2011-03-19 |    16 | NA         |
|  1 | 2011-03-20 |    17 | NA         |
|  1 | 2011-03-21 |    18 | NA         |
|  1 | 2011-03-22 |    11 | NA         |
|  1 | 2011-03-23 |    15 | NA         |
|  1 | 2011-03-24 |    12 | 2011-03-24 |
|  1 | 2011-03-25 |    13 | NA         |
|  1 | 2011-03-26 |    15 | NA         |
|  2 | 2011-06-11 |    48 | NA         |
|  2 | 2011-06-12 |    49 | NA         |
|  2 | 2011-06-13 |    50 | NA         |
|  2 | 2011-06-14 |    57 | NA         |
|  2 | 2011-06-15 |    60 | NA         |
|  2 | 2011-06-16 |    49 | NA         |
|  2 | 2011-06-17 |    64 | NA         |
|  2 | 2011-06-18 |    63 | NA         |
|  2 | 2011-06-19 |    67 | 2011-06-19 |
|  2 | 2011-06-20 |    70 | NA         |
|  2 | 2011-06-21 |    58 | NA         |
|  2 | 2011-06-22 |    65 | NA         |
|  2 | 2011-06-23 |    57 | NA         |
|  2 | 2011-06-24 |    55 | NA         |
|  2 | 2011-06-25 |    57 | NA         |
|  2 | 2011-06-26 |    60 | NA         |
+----+------------+-------+------------+
```

Eventually, I hope to make the following table with a new column.

```
+----+------------+-------+------------+---------------+
| ID |    Date    | Price | EventDate  | BuyHoldReturn |
+----+------------+-------+------------+---------------+
|  1 | 2011-03-06 |    10 | NA         | NA            |
|  1 | 2011-03-07 |     9 | NA         | -0.1          |
|  1 | 2011-03-08 |    12 | NA         | 0.2           |
|  1 | 2011-03-09 |    14 | NA         | 0.4           |
|  1 | 2011-03-10 |    15 | NA         | 0.5           |
|  1 | 2011-03-11 |    17 | NA         | 0.7           |
|  1 | 2011-03-12 |    12 | 2011-03-12 | 0.2           |
|  1 | 2011-03-13 |    14 | NA         | 0.4           |
|  1 | 2011-03-14 |    17 | NA         | 0.7           |
|  1 | 2011-03-15 |    14 | NA         | 0.4           |
|  1 | 2011-03-16 |    17 | NA         | 0.7           |
|  1 | 2011-03-17 |    16 | NA         | 0.6           |
|  1 | 2011-03-18 |    15 | NA         | NA            |
|  1 | 2011-03-19 |    16 | NA         | 0.066666667   |
|  1 | 2011-03-20 |    17 | NA         | 0.133333333   |
|  1 | 2011-03-21 |    18 | NA         | 0.2           |
|  1 | 2011-03-22 |    11 | NA         | -0.266666667  |
|  1 | 2011-03-23 |    15 | NA         | 0             |
|  1 | 2011-03-24 |    12 | 2011-03-24 | -0.2          |
|  1 | 2011-03-25 |    13 | NA         | -0.133333333  |
|  1 | 2011-03-26 |    15 | NA         | 0             |
|  2 | 2011-06-11 |    48 | NA         | NA            |
|  2 | 2011-06-12 |    49 | NA         | NA            |
|  2 | 2011-06-13 |    50 | NA         | NA            |
|  2 | 2011-06-14 |    57 | NA         | 0.14          |
|  2 | 2011-06-15 |    60 | NA         | 0.2           |
|  2 | 2011-06-16 |    49 | NA         | -0.02         |
|  2 | 2011-06-17 |    64 | NA         | 0.28          |
|  2 | 2011-06-18 |    63 | NA         | 0.26          |
|  2 | 2011-06-19 |    67 | 2011-06-19 | 0.34          |
|  2 | 2011-06-20 |    70 | NA         | 0.4           |
|  2 | 2011-06-21 |    58 | NA         | 0.16          |
|  2 | 2011-06-22 |    65 | NA         | 0.3           |
|  2 | 2011-06-23 |    57 | NA         | 0.14          |
|  2 | 2011-06-24 |    55 | NA         | 0.1           |
|  2 | 2011-06-25 |    57 | NA         | NA            |
|  2 | 2011-06-26 |    60 | NA         | NA            |
+----+------------+-------+------------+---------------+
```

I have an idea of using the code below but couldn't figure out how to calculate the 11 buy and hold returns around the event date.

```
data<-data%>%
group_by(ID)%>%
mutate(BuyHoldReturn=ifelse(Date==EventDate, ....
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do use `dplyr` as follows:

```
# ensure Date and EventDate are Date columns
df <- df %>% mutate(across(c(Date,EventDate), ~as.Date(.x)))


left_join(
  select(df,ID, Date), 
  inner_join(df %>% select(-EventDate),filter(df,!is.na(EventDate)) %>% distinct(ID, EventDate), by="ID") %>%
    filter(abs(EventDate-Date)<=6) %>% 
    group_by(ID, EventDate) %>% 
    mutate(BuyHoldReturn = c(NA,Price[-1]/Price[1]-1)),
  by=c("ID", "Date")
)
```

Output:

```
   ID       Date Price  EventDate BuyHoldReturn
1   1 2011-03-06    10 2011-03-12            NA
2   1 2011-03-07     9 2011-03-12   -0.10000000
3   1 2011-03-08    12 2011-03-12    0.20000000
4   1 2011-03-09    14 2011-03-12    0.40000000
5   1 2011-03-10    15 2011-03-12    0.50000000
6   1 2011-03-11    17 2011-03-12    0.70000000
7   1 2011-03-12    12 2011-03-12    0.20000000
8   1 2011-03-13    14 2011-03-12    0.40000000
9   1 2011-03-14    17 2011-03-12    0.70000000
10  1 2011-03-15    14 2011-03-12    0.40000000
11  1 2011-03-16    17 2011-03-12    0.70000000
12  1 2011-03-17    16 2011-03-12    0.60000000
13  1 2011-03-18    15 2011-03-12    0.50000000
14  1 2011-03-18    15 2011-03-24            NA
15  1 2011-03-19    16 2011-03-24    0.06666667
16  1 2011-03-20    17 2011-03-24    0.13333333
17  1 2011-03-21    18 2011-03-24    0.20000000
18  1 2011-03-22    11 2011-03-24   -0.26666667
19  1 2011-03-23    15 2011-03-24    0.00000000
20  1 2011-03-24    12 2011-03-24   -0.20000000
21  1 2011-03-25    13 2011-03-24   -0.13333333
22  1 2011-03-26    15 2011-03-24    0.00000000
23  2 2011-06-11    NA       <NA>            NA
24  2 2011-06-12    NA       <NA>            NA
25  2 2011-06-13    50 2011-06-19            NA
26  2 2011-06-14    57 2011-06-19    0.14000000
27  2 2011-06-15    60 2011-06-19    0.20000000
28  2 2011-06-16    49 2011-06-19   -0.02000000
29  2 2011-06-17    64 2011-06-19    0.28000000
30  2 2011-06-18    63 2011-06-19    0.26000000
31  2 2011-06-19    67 2011-06-19    0.34000000
32  2 2011-06-20    70 2011-06-19    0.40000000
33  2 2011-06-21    58 2011-06-19    0.16000000
34  2 2011-06-22    65 2011-06-19    0.30000000
35  2 2011-06-23    57 2011-06-19    0.14000000
36  2 2011-06-24    55 2011-06-19    0.10000000
37  2 2011-06-25    57 2011-06-19    0.14000000
38  2 2011-06-26    NA       <NA>            NA
```

This can be done similarly using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[,(c("Date", "EventDate")):=lapply(.SD, as.Date), .SDcols=c("Date", "EventDate")]
df[,!c("EventDate")][unique(df[!is.na(EventDate), .(ID, EventDate)]), on="ID", allow.cartesian=T][
  abs(EventDate-Date)<=6][,BuyHoldReturn:=c(NA,Price[-1]/Price[1]-1), .(ID,EventDate)][
    df[,.(ID,Date)], on=.(ID,Date)
]
```

Both of the above approaches use cartesian joins, and then filter. If you have a very large table and you are looking for some increase in speed, you can also use a `data.table` non-equi join to isolate the rows before and after the `EventDate`(s) for each `ID`

1. load library and set data to data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)
```

2. Create an events frame, which just has the ID and Events

```
events = unique(df[!is.na(EventDate),.(ID,EventDate)])

      ID  EventDate
   <int>     <IDat>
1:     1 2011-03-12
2:     1 2011-03-24
3:     2 2011-06-19
```

3. Add some helper columns to the frames (this facilitates retention of columns in non-equi joins

```
events[, eDate:=EventDate]
df[, `:=`(s=Date-6, e=Date+6)]
```

3. Use a non-equi join: require ID to match and EventDate to be between the lower and upper bounds created above (i.e. `s` and `e`)

```
bhr = events[df, on=.(ID, EventDate>=s, EventDate<=e), nomatch=0]
```

4. Generate the `BuyHoldReturn` column, by `ID` and `EventDate`

```
bhr = bhr[, .(Date, BuyHoldReturn=c(NA, Price[-1]/Price[1] -1)), by = .(ID,eDate)]
```

5. Merge back on the original frame to retain the rows with `NA`, and select columns with desired name and arrangement.

```
bhr[df,on=.(ID,Date),.(ID,Date,Price,EventDate=i.EventDate,BuyHoldReturn)]
```

Input:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Date = c("2011-03-06", 
"2011-03-07", "2011-03-08", "2011-03-09", "2011-03-10", "2011-03-11", 
"2011-03-12", "2011-03-13", "2011-03-14", "2011-03-15", "2011-03-16", 
"2011-03-17", "2011-03-18", "2011-03-19", "2011-03-20", "2011-03-21", 
"2011-03-22", "2011-03-23", "2011-03-24", "2011-03-25", "2011-03-26", 
"2011-06-11", "2011-06-12", "2011-06-13", "2011-06-14", "2011-06-15", 
"2011-06-16", "2011-06-17", "2011-06-18", "2011-06-19", "2011-06-20", 
"2011-06-21", "2011-06-22", "2011-06-23", "2011-06-24", "2011-06-25", 
"2011-06-26"), Price = c(10L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 12L, 14L, 
17L, 14L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 11L, 15L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 
48L, 49L, 50L, 57L, 60L, 49L, 64L, 63L, 67L, 70L, 58L, 65L, 57L, 
55L, 57L, 60L), EventDate = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "2011-03-12", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "2011-03-24", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "2011-06-19", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -37L
))
```

Comment: Thank you very very much for such a great answer langtang! I learned a lot from your comment. With regards to the first code, I had the 'error in select unused arguments' at first, but then after explicitly specifying to use dplyr package, it ran perfectly! I hope who are not familiar with these issues, just like me, could save some time by reading how to fix this issue from this website https://www.statology.org/dplyr-error-in-select-unused-arguments/